# disable automatic autosummary created by numpydoc

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc

Is it possible do *disable* the complete [autosummary](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html) when using [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html)?

I've got a class derived from a [Python standard library class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet), which has many public methods. My custom class should work as a wrapper, directly providing methods to communicate with my device using its protocol.
Therefore I only want to include a few selected inherited methods in the *autosummary* table.

```
.. autoclass:: my_module.MyClass
   :members:
   :show-inheritance:

   .. autosummary::
      my_method
      another_method
```

The `..autosummary::` block does exactly what I desire, but `..autoclass::` automatically creates a full methods table. Is there a way to disable this feature?

---

### Edit (clarification)

Using the *autosummary* directive directly, I'm able to produce a method table containing only `my_method` and `another_method`:

```
.. autosummary::
   my_method
   another_method
```

However, when using *autoclass* or *automodule* **without a following *autosummary* directive**, I still get a method table looking exactly like the one created by the *autosummary* block above, only with all methods described:

```
.. autoclass:: my_module.MyClass
   :members:
   :show-inheritance
```

---

### Edit 2

The "complete" autosummary table is being generated by [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc).

Comment: `autoclass` generates an own `autosummary` block, which I'd like to configure (or disable) in order to get the behaviour of the explicit `.. autosummary::` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" was not inside *autodoc* or *autosummary*.
Though not mentioned in the question I'm using [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt), which was generating the additional *autosummary* table.

As described in [numpydoc's documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc), this feature can be disabled by adding `numpydoc_show_inherited_class_members = False` to the sphinx `conf.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `:members:` tag, or include a comma separated list after `:members:` of only the methods you want to include in your documentation.

Comment: This affects only the methods described in detail, not the table generated by autosummary